# Rsync error code 23

Tags: backup, usb-drive, rsync

I am trying to back up a server into a flashdrive with rsync:

```
rsync -rv --delete /home/computername/filename /dev/disk/by-label/Flashdrivename
```

It fails, with:

> sending incremental file list
>   rsync: delete_file: unlink(Flashdrivename) failed: Permission denied (13)
>   could not make way for new regular file: filename
>
> sent 53 bytes  received 138 bytes  382.00 bytes/sec
>   total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
>   rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23)  at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]

if someone knows what's the problem i would be very grateful if you told me.

Comment: I think your Flash drive is write-protected. `rsync` tries to copy `filename` to it, but there is already a file with the same name on it, and `rsync` is not allowed to overwrite it. You will get a similar error if you try to manually copy the file.

Comment: @Jos i formated the flash drive so there would not be any same files and now when i but that command it says:

Comment: sending incremental file list
[sender] make_file(filename,*,0)
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=20660
recv_file_name(filename)
received 1 names
recv_file_list done

Comment: get_local_name count=1 /dev/disk/by-label/flashdrivename
generator starting pid=20660
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
recv_generator(flashdrivename,1)
send_files(1, /home/servername/serverfile)
send_files mapped /home/servername/serverfile of size 0
calling match_sums /home/servername/serverfile
all_databases.sql
sending file_sum
false_alarms=0 hash_hits=0 matches=0
sender finished /home/servername/serverfile
generate_files phase=1
recv_files(1) starting
recv_files(flashdrivename)

Comment: rsync: mkstemp "/dev/disk/by-label/.flashdrivename.vEwxZB" failed: Permission denied (13)
got file_sum
send_files phase=1
recv_files phase=1
generate_files phase=2
send_files phase=2
send files finished
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
recv_files phase=2
recv_files finished
generate_files phase=3
generate_files finished

sent 96 bytes  received 576 bytes  1,344.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]

Comment: [sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1196): about to call exit(23)

Comment: Please edit your question and add this material so we can make sense of it.